# EOFException using HTTPUrlConnection from Android Mobile Application

Tags: android, apache, android-studio, osx-yosemite, soap-client

I have an Android Appliation and I'm getting EOFException while calling connection.getInputStream(). I'm calling this to consume a soap service provided by my local PHP server using Apache.

```
        // create url connection
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(getServerSoap()).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+content.getBytes().length);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
        output.write(content.getBytes());
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        // EOFException here.
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
```

I`ve checked similar answers on stackoverflow, regarding using:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
```

And

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

But none of this worked for me. If I use the same code to call this servide on production mode on a Linux - CentOS 6, it works fine. Is there anything to do with my mac?

How can I fix this issue? I`m running this code in development using:

1. Mac OS X Yosemite
2. Apache with MySQL on Mac
3. Android Studio with SDK 22